# Outlook signature html

Tags: html, outlook

I am trying to make signature in html for my Outlook mail.

The problem is that everything looks great in browser but in outlook is too wide.

This should look like in the browser.

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sig" style="min-width: 680px; min-height: 82px; line-height: 18px; padding: 24px 0 0 30px; font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">

    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" style="float: left; border: none;" />
    </a>
    <div style="margin-left: 40px; padding-left: 20px;">
        <span style="display: block; font-size:13px; color: #404040; margin-bottom: 3px;">Name Surnamek&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="display: block; font-size:10px; color: #404040; margin-bottom: 3px;">TT Test&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 0px;">
        </br>
        <strong><a title="TEST" style="color: #404040; text-decoration: none;">Company Name</a></strong>
        <br /> tel. &nbsp+00 (0) 00 – 000 00 00 </br>fax. +00 (0) 00 – 000 00 00</br>
        </br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</br>
        </br>
    </div>

    <hr style="width: 680px; float: left;"></hr>
    </br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </br>
    </br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</br>
    </br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</br>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt outlook supports min-width. Use width instead

Comment: is it possible to make responsive signature?

Comment: Still doesn't work without min-width.
http://imgur.com/a/DB4Yc